# Opportunity Amount Field Permission with Record Types

Tags: permissions, record-type

Our Salesforce admin set up two different record types for Opportunity.  1) General 2) Overseas

We have these scenarios to meet:

```
1) User 1 with Profile 1 to see all the fields of Opportunity.
2) User 2 with Profile 2 to see all the fields of Opportunity except Amount
3) User 3 with Profile 3 to see Amount field in Overseas Opportunity record type but not on General record type.
```

My approach was to use field security level and page layout.  Only problem is that although User 3 has a page layout without the Amount field in Overseas Opportunity record type, User 3 is still able to pull reports with Amount field.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the current OWD and FLS are on Account and Opportunity objects. Using page layouts is NOT the way to do this! Do you have any sharing rules currently set up? Are these users on Opportunity teams related to these Opps, etc?

Comment: The OWD for opportunity is Public/Read Write, and FLS for amount is visible to User 1 only.  What do you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to hide Amount field from User 3 and instead create a formula field that checked the record type and copied over the amount field when it is equal to Overseas, else be null. Then give User 3 permissions to see the formula and not the Amount field. Although it would be read only.

Comment: Definitely the simplest...

Comment: That worked.  Perfect!  Great solution.